# (Python Pandas) After grouping, my counts are no longer accurate

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

**Disclaimer: I am new to python pandas**

Hello, after grouping data, I realized my counts decreased from 100k to 4k. From what I have been told, NaN values are skipped in a groupby. **What is the cleanest way to aggregate data and end up with the original counts?** Is there a way to not drop NaN values? Ideally, if I have to populate a temporary value for the columns containing NaN, would I be able to change it back to NaN after grouping and summing the counts?

**Example data:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'City':["Tucson","Tucson","Portland","San Diego"], 
                "Event Type":[1,None,3,2], 
                 "date":[1,1,3,4],
                 "Event Count":[1,1,1,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"City":["San Diego", "Tucson", "Portland"], 
                "zip":[1,2,3], "state":["CA", "AZ", "OR"], 
                "country":["USA","USA","USA"]})
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how="left", on="City")

grouped = df3.groupby(['City', 'Event Type','date','zip','country'], as_index=False)['Event Count'].sum()
```

Leaves me with the result:

```
City, Event Type, date, zip, state, country, Event Count
Tucson,1,1,2,AZ,USA,1 (Should be 2, but dropped due to second row missing event type)
Portland,3,3,3,OR,USA,1
San Diego,2,4,1,CA,USA,1
```

Comment: First of all, groupby will automatically ignore rows that has any NA values in the columns you are grouping, so for that row to be counted, you need to fill in a value. Based on the expected solution you have, you should impute it to be 1 for Tucson, but I don't know if 1 will work in general for all your data (you said you have 100k) because your groupby is very specific (5 columns). `df3.fillna(1).groupby(['City', 'Event Type','date','zip','country'], as_index=False)['Event Count'].sum()`

Comment: Would method would I use for changing these values back after grouping?

Comment: `grouped` is actually a separate object from your `df3`, In my code, `df3.fillna(1)` will return a new dataframe object, and then apply groupby on that, so it won't change your original df3. In a different word, you can just keep a copy of the original df somewhere.